# Swift filter array of strings

Tags: ios, arrays, string, swift, filtering

I've had troubles filtering array of keywords (strings) in swift ,My code:

```
self.filteredKeywords=filter(keywords.allValues, {(keyword:NSString) ->                                              
  Bool in
    let words=keyword as? NSString
    return words?.containsString(searchText)
  })
```

As `AnyObject` can't be subtype of `NSString`, I'm stuck with this!

Comment: What is the exact error you get? What is printed if you try `NSLog("\(keywords)")`?

Comment: Just notice that you are returning an optional. Hope this helps

Comment: it doesn't run it gives me the error mentioned above : "AnyObject isn't a subtype of NSString"

Comment: Did either of the below answers answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift 4.2 provides a new way to do this:

```
var theBigLebowski = ["The Dude", "Angry Walter", "Maude Lebowski", "Donny Kerabatsos", "The Big Lebowski", "Little Larry Sellers"]

// after removeAll -> ["The Dude", "Angry Walter", "Donny Kerabatsos", "Little Larry Sellers"]
theBigLebowski.removeAll{ $0.contains("Lebowski")}
print(theBigLebowski)
```

Answer (score 16):

[Updated for Swift 2.0]

As `NSString` is toll-free bridged to Swift `String`, just avoid the coercions with:

```
  3> ["abc", "bcd", "xyz"].filter() { nil != $0.rangeOfString("bc") }
$R1: [String] = 2 values {
  [0] = "abc"
  [1] = "bcd"
}
```

But, if you think `allValues` aren't strings:

```
(keywords.allValues as? [String]).filter() { nil != $0.rangeOfString("bc") }
```

which returns an optional array.

Answer (score 4):

Your `filter` is over `[AnyObject]`, but your closure takes `NSString`. These need to match. Also, your result needs to be a `Bool`, not a `Bool?`. You can address these simply like this:

```
self.filteredKeywords = filter(keywords.allValues, {
    let keyword = $0 as? NSString
    return keyword?.containsString(searchText) ?? false
})
```

This accepts `AnyObject` and then tries to coerce it down to `NSString`. It then nil-coalleces (`??`) the result to make sure it always is a `Bool`.

I'd recommend, though, treating `keywords` as a `[String:String]` rather than an `NSDictionary`. That would get rid of all the complications of `AnyObject`. Then you can just do this:

```
self.filteredKeywords = keywords.values.filter { $0.rangeOfString(searchText) != nil }
```

Whenever possible, convert Foundation collections into Swift collections as soon as you can and store those. If you have incoming Foundation objects, you can generally convert them easily with techniques like:

```
let dict = nsdict as? [String:String] ?? [:]
```

Or you can do the following to convert them such that they'll crash in debug (but silently "work" in release):

```
func failWith<T>(msg: String, value: T) -> T {
    assertionFailure(msg)
    return value
}

let dict = nsdict as? [String:String] ?? failWith("Couldn't convert \(d)", [:])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is both a problem with GoZoner's answer for certain data types and also a slightly better way to do this.  The following examples can show this:

```
let animalArray: NSMutableArray = ["Dog","Cat","Otter","Deer","Rabbit"]
let filteredAnimals = animalArray.filter { $0.rangeOfString("er") != nil }
print("filteredAnimals:", filteredAnimals)

filteredAnimals: [Dog, Cat, Otter, Deer, Rabbit]
```

Likely not the set you expected!

However this works fine this way if we don't type animalArray as an **NSMutableArray**:

```
let animalArray = ["Dog","Cat","Otter","Deer","Rabbit"]
let filteredAnimals = animalArray.filter { $0.rangeOfString("er") != nil }
print("filteredAnimals:", filteredAnimals)

filteredAnimals: [Otter, Deer]
```

However I'd recommend using **$0.contains() instead of $0.rangeOfString() != nil** because it functions in both circumstances and slightly enhances the readability of the code:

```
let animalArray: NSMutableArray = ["Dog","Cat","Otter","Deer","Rabbit"]
let filteredAnimals = animalArray.filter { $0.contains("er") }
print("filteredAnimals:", filteredAnimals)

filteredAnimals: [Otter, Deer]
```

Comment: what if you had an array of filters like mime types to apply to a string  instead of just one string to filter like "er"?   filter=["stuff", "bear", "bottle"]